# Docker does not release ports after stop and remove all container

Tags: docker, binding, port

Docker doesn't release port binding after I stop and remove all of containers in my computer.
Do you have any suggestion?

```
ricky@ricky-ubuntu:~$ sudo docker -v
Docker version 1.12.2, build bb80604
ricky@ricky-ubuntu:~$ sudo docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
ricky@ricky-ubuntu:~$ sudo netstat -nlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5939          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1464/teamviewerd
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1487/dnsmasq    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3623/cupsd      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2771/docker-proxy
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1196/mongod     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1325/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5900            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3485/vino-server
tcp6       0      0 :::9999                 :::*                    LISTEN      2597/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2787/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      2755/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::7091                 :::*                    LISTEN      2763/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      3623/cupsd      
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      2779/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::9888                 :::*                    LISTEN      2737/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::9889                 :::*                    LISTEN      2728/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::9090                 :::*                    LISTEN      2745/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::5800                 :::*                    LISTEN      3485/vino-server
tcp6       0      0 :::5900                 :::*                    LISTEN      3485/vino-server
tcp6       0      0 :::9997                 :::*                    LISTEN      2719/docker-proxy
```

Comment: Restart docker? :) Works for me all the time.

Comment: I've restarted docker-engine with sudo service docker restart (and restarted machine after that), but it was still not working.

Comment: Did you do <docker ps -a> to ensure it shows nothing? Sometimes dangling containers can be using ports.

Comment: Yes, I did. You can see the above output. <sudo docker ps -a> totally empty.

Comment: I have same problem. I stop all container, run `service docker restart`, `docker container prune`. But netstat show my port :/.

Answer (score 11):

If "docker-compose down" or stopping and removing containers didnt help, I quit docker, then check if the docker.backend is still running (com.docker.backend.exe for windows).
Killing that service frees my ports.

Another approach would be "reset to factory defaults" in settings. But that should be the last used solution till it removes everything you set up in Docker.

Comment: And, after trying the solutions of @Dagger87, try terminating all processes of `Java.exe` or `OpenJDK` suspicious. That may work.