# Close Docker port when container is stopped

Tags: c#, docker, networking, tcpclient

need some help. Here is the situation.

Inside a Docker container there is a service running that is accessible via TCP port.

There is another application written in .NET, that is not contained within a container, communicating with the containerized service via the open port.

The .NET application uses the TcpClient class to connect and write bytes across the socket; there is a check on the TcpClient.Connected to ensure it is true before writing. Everything works great.

To test resilience, I stop the container containing the service. It was excepted that the TcpClient.Connected would become false or a SocketException would be raised on write; or at least something would happen as the containerized service is no longer available.

This does not happen. TcpClient remains connected and no exceptions are raised.

Some investigation with netset -nabo shows that the TCP port remains open and the connection between the application and the port remains.

Theory is Docker keeps the port open, and the connection with the application, even if the container and the server inside the container has stopped.

Does anyone know whether this is correct?

The goal is to simulate a failure on the port to see how the TcpClient will respond. So, does anyone know a good way to keep Docker running and close the port?

Thanks you reading, hope you can help.

Comment: some additional information, it is com.docker.backend.exe that keeps the port open. keeps it in state FIN_WAIT2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40159468/docker-do-not-release-ports-after-stop-and-remove-all-container

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker does not release ports after stop and remove all container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40159468/docker-does-not-release-ports-after-stop-and-remove-all-container)

Answer (score 3):

Stopping a container does not free up the port. Any application sending data to that open port will still continue to send data and no socket exception is raised.

Why? It is speculated that Docker (on Windows) has a proxy to the Linux virtual machine that routes traffic on the port to the relevant application running in the container. The container might be stopped but the proxy keeps the port open.

If you want the port to close the container needs to be deleted.

This might not be much of a solution if the container has configuration or SSL certificates, etc. In this case create a Dockerfile and copy configuration in. This way the container can be deleted and the socket exception is raised.

Happy coding.